# Code optimization help (loop to tensor operation)

Tags: python, numpy, loops, optimization, tensor

I have a very long loop 2*40*40*40*40 (around 5 million iteration) and i feel its unnecessary and can be reduced to a tensor operation. The original code run around 34 sec, had a lot of numerical operations in the loop, i have managed to reduce them to a constant, making the code run in 7.8 seconds. But i still feel like it can be reduced to a <1 second operation if i remove the loops and replace them with a tensor operation. Here is the code, M1 and M2 are 40:

```
 for t in range(2):
    for i2 in range(M1):
        for j2 in range(M2):
            for i1 in range(M1):
                for j1 in range(M2):
                    U_out[i2][j2][t] += U_in[i1][j1][t] * constants[j1,i1,j2,i2,t]
```

Update: After some more effort, I've managed to reduce the time to 0.1 sec with:

```
for t in range(2):
  for i2 in range(M1):
     for j2 in range(M2):
       U_out[i2,j2,t] += np.sum(U_in[:,:,t] * constants[:,:,j2,i2,t])
```

It feels like I'm missing the last part of a puzzle.

Comment: Glad you were able to optimize this. 34 seconds down to 0.1 is a great achievement, and I'd recommend only optimizing it further if it's actually useful. If you're looking for more input, it might be useful to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's possible you could further reframe this problem as matrix math across a few dimensions by expanding some arrays and leverage einstein notation

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Answer (score 1):

Please adjust the dimensions in this example, I am not sure if I got it right. So we have a small testing array to work with and compare the results:

```
import numpy as np

U_out = np.empty((4, 4, 2))

constants = np.random.random_sample((4, 4, 4, 4, 2))
U_in = np.random.random_sample((4, 4, 2))

for t in range(2):
    for i2 in range(4):
        for j2 in range(4):
            for i1 in range(4):
                for j1 in range(4):
                    U_out[i2][j2][t] += U_in[i1][j1][t] * constants[j1,i1,j2,i2,t]

U_out2 = U_out.copy()
print(U_out)

for t in range(2):
  for i2 in range(4):
     for j2 in range(4):
       U_out[i2,j2,t] += np.sum(U_in[:,:,t] * constants[:,:,j2,i2,t])

print(U_out - U_out2)
```